# Using user from OWIN context in Nancy

Tags: f#, authorization, owin, nancy, katana

I've got a Nancy project that is hosted with OWIN. Currently it has its own was of authenticating users. The plan is to change it and make my project compatible with an external authentication model - i.e. SAML-based; I've got a local Identity Provider and managed to handle communication between my service and the IdP. I achieved this by using the Kentor.AuthServices library (https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices)

```
let CreateSPOptions() : SPOptions =
    let spOptions = new SPOptions()
    spOptions.EntityId <- new EntityId("<my_service_ID>")
    spOptions.ReturnUrl <- new Uri("http://localhost:5012/login")
    spOptions.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm <- "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"
    spOptions

let ConfigureAuthOptions() : KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions =
    let spOptions = CreateSPOptions()
    let authServicesOptions = new KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
    authServicesOptions.SPOptions <- spOptions
    let idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("<my_IdP_ID>"), spOptions)
    idp.AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse <- true
    idp.Binding <- Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect
    idp.MetadataLocation <- @"Metadata\provider.xml"
    authServicesOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
    authServicesOptions

let Configure (app : IAppBuilder) =
    let cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    cookieOptions.LoginPath <- new PathString("/Login")
    cookieOptions.LogoutPath <- new PathString("/Logout")
    cookieOptions.AuthenticationType <- "KentorAuthServices"
    cookieOptions.AuthenticationMode <- AuthenticationMode.Active
    cookieOptions.Provider <- new CookieAuthenticationProvider()

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions) |> ignore
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("KentorAuthServices")
    app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(ConfigureAuthOptions()) |> ignore
    app
```

However, as a result the user information is now stored in Owin Context, so I can't rely on `this.Context.CurrentUser` (where `this` refers to a current Nancy Module) and I can't secure my modules using:

```
type SecuredModule() as this =
    inherit NancyModule()

    do
        this.RequiresAuthentication()

        this.Get.["/"] <- ....
```

I know there's functionality provided in `Nancy.MSOwinSecurity` package that allows me to refer to OwinContext e.g.

```
type SecuredModule() as this =
    inherit NancyModule()

    do
        this.RequiresMSOwinAuthentication()

        this.Get.["/"] <- ...
```

But the thing is there are many tests associated with the project that assume the user info is stored in Nancy context. Vast majority of the tests is based on the mock object:

```
let createBrowser rootFolder =
    let docStore = DocumentStore(rootFolder)
    let config (w:ConfigurableBootstrapper.ConfigurableBootstrapperConfigurator) = 
        w.Module(new UnsecuredModule(docStore))
         .Module(new SecuredModule(docStore)) 
         .RequestStartup(fun _ _ (context: NancyContext) ->
            context.CurrentUser <- new UserIdentity("MyServiceUnitTests", Seq.empty)) 
        |> ignore
```

I've tried the same when handling a response from my IdP and manually overrode context.CurrentUser, but the information was lost after a redirection:

```
type LoginModule(userDatabase: UserDatabase) as this = 
    inherit NancyModule()

    do
        this.Get.["/login"] <-
            fun _ ->
                match this.Context.GetMSOwinUser() with
                | null ->
                    let authenticationManager = this.Context.GetAuthenticationManager();
                    let properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                    properties.RedirectUri <- "/Web.Documents/login"
                    authenticationManager.Challenge(properties, "KentorAuthServices")
                    HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized |> box
                | user ->
                    let userName = user.Identity.Name
                    let ipAddress = this.Context.Request.UserHostAddress
                    Log.Info "{@user} {@ipaddress} logged in" [ 
                        "user"      => userName
                        "ipaddress" => ipAddress 
                    ]
                    this.Context.CurrentUser <- new UserIdentity("MyServiceUnitTests", Seq.empty)
                    this.Context.GetRedirect("~/") |> box
```

Obviously, I don't want to make too many changes to my service. Ideally I'd like it to move somehow the user information to Nancy Context - then I'd be happy to go, as I don't need to adjust the ~50 tests as well. What's the best solution here ?